# Learning GURPS with Discworld RPG?

Tags: gurps

I'm a big fan of Discworld, and was considering getting the latest edition of Discworld RPG, even if it's just for the lore. That said, I don't know if I'd be able to find anyone to play it with (don't know anyone who's into Discworld, and idk if there's people playing it online), but I may be able to find someone playing GURPS, which made me wonder:

Since Discworld RPG is a standalone book, is it enough to learn GURPS? As in, if I read Discworld RPG, could I play any GURPS campaign?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @vicky_molokh  Oh, I did assume people play GURPS online, but I was thinking particularly of Discworld GURPS. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes. But no GURPS game will teach you everything about GURPS.

GURPS should be viewed as a toolkit, not a final RPG. GURPS has many detailed systems that build on the core rule set. A GURPS GM is expected to select from these systems when designing a game.

Compare this to a specific RPG like DND or Shadowrun. The level of details in the mechanics are specifically tuned to high-magic high-fantasy or gritty fantasy-cyberpunk, respectively.

For example, games focusing on highly detailed martial combat will prefer advanced rules in GURPS Martial Arts. Games with a focus on shooting tactics will benefit from GURPS Tactical Shooting. And there are many magic and power systems that may or not be appropriate.

Even the GURPS skill system are advantages/disadvantages are modular and should be curated and designed for the campaign at hand.

No one GURPS campaign will ever teach a GM all that there is about GURPS. But it will teach the basic ideas and mechanics. When it comes time to start a different game, the GM should select the appropriate mechanical systems for that campaign.

For more on guidance on GURPS as a toolkit, the Mook's book "How to be a GURPS GM" is very good reading.

Answer (score 8):

The new edition of the Discworld RPG has a built in, somewhat cut-down version of the GURPS 4e rules. It leaves out rules and concepts intended for high technology, psionics, and superheroes, and it has a magic system of its own. GURPS has *lots* of magic systems, so that isn't a big deal, but it is the major thing that is unique to the book.

Learning the Discworld rules will certainly teach you all the core mechanics of GURPS, and won't teach you anything that's wrong in GURPS 4e. It won't miss out much that's useful for a more generic fantasy game, but it won't equip you fully for all the kinds of games that can be played with GURPS.

Answer (score -1):

There is a free booklet called GURPS Lite, which is specifically designed to give you a basic understanding of how to use the system.  That, combined with the campaign book, should be enough to get you through the basics.

GURPS Lite can be downloaded for free at: http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/lite/

Comment: (According to the SJG Web site's [*GURPS Discworld*](http://www.sjgames.com/discworld/) entry, "You need no other books to play. It includes the material from the previous edition of the game and its supplement, *Discworld Also* — all of it updated to reflect the events of the Discworld novels released since then, as well as the rules of *GURPS Fourth Edition.* However, if you've the book and want to dispute that claim, that's cool.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, that's why I asked, i've read that but I don't know if it's enough to "just play discworld" or if it's enough to play any GURPS campaign. I've read it's more streamlined than the basic set, and it has less examples and such, but nothing that answers my question